# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

DevOps Stack Exchange's [second pro-temp moderator election](https://devops.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Preston Martin] [image: Peter Turner]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5119820082184192).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who voted, I'm a little confused if I'm a pro-tem mod or an elected one here, although I guess it doesn't much matter.  But, if we get devops out of beta, there'll be another election, right?

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes this was a Pro Temp election. There was an election and voting the only difference is if there had only been two qualified nominees they would have just been appointed since this was a Pro Temp election. In the future when DevOps moves out of Beta there would be a graduation election.